# How to recognize programmatically that application is installed vs development mode?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to get information about license info of my app and MSDN docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694065.aspx) advice to use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator`  class for that purposes during development/testing and when submitting app to store replace that class with `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp`.

I wonder if there is any way to check in code (javascript in my case) if app is already installed from store so my code should use proper class and I won't have to remember every time I submit update of app to store to replacing those classes properly.

Comment: Does js have compiler directives?

Comment: @mydogisbox js does not have compiler, so I doubt so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found at solution as described here [WinJS are there #DEBUG or #RELEASE directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703378/winjs-are-there-debug-or-release-directives) . Not ideal, but works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I could not find such thing. In fact, LicenseInfo is what provides information about the store listing.

I use a `config.js` file to keep settings at place which change between development and production. For example - if your app talks to a service, service URL also will likely change between development and production; the service might be running at localhost for development and for production in azure environment. I keep a bool in here and change by hand.

I have not automated it fully. but it is likely possible. need to dig through the msbuild logs for the build created for the store. if there is configuration setting found, then project can have two config.dev.js and config.release.js and msbuild need to conditionally pick the right file. I haven't looked into this yet.